# What is a good pattern for isolated multithreaded computation over a shared object?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Imagine that we have some object `foo: Foo`. Some of the time, when we need to do multithreaded computation on `foo`, we clone and move it. However, there are also times when we don't need to clone it, which may be expensive, and can instead put it in an `Arc` to share its data between threads. In the question title, "shared" means "inside an `Arc`", and "isolated" means in only some places, i.e. not program-wide.

I can think of two umbrella ways to do this:

1. Have the callee consume the object and wrap/unwrap in `Arc` internally, returning the object along with any other data in a tuple.
2. Accept `Arc<Foo>` as the callee, delegating wrap/unwrap responsibility to the caller.

However, neither of these seems particularly clean. (1) has a complicated return type that might complicate or hinder e.g. chained operations, and (2) forces the caller to do work that it shouldn't really need to know about.

I'm curious if there is an idiomatic pattern for handling this sort of situation. For reference, I've included a basic example of the two patterns I describe above.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(0);

    // pattern 1
    let (foo, _res) = process(foo);

    // pattern 2
    let foo = Arc::new(foo);
    let _res = process2(Arc::clone(&foo));
    let foo = Arc::try_unwrap(foo).unwrap();
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(u8);

impl Clone for Foo {
    /// an expensive clone operation that we want to avoid when possible
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10));
        Foo(self.0)
    }
}

/// complicated return type
fn process(foo: Foo) -> (Foo, u8) {
    let foo = Arc::new(foo);

    let mut threads = Vec::<JoinHandle<()>>::new();
    for _ in 1..=5 {
        let f = Arc::clone(&foo);
        let t = thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", f);
        });
        threads.push(t);
    }
    threads.into_iter().for_each(|t| t.join().unwrap());

    (Arc::try_unwrap(foo).unwrap(), 1)
}

/// forces the caller to do work that should be hidden
fn process2(foo: Arc<Foo>) -> u8 {
    let mut threads = Vec::<JoinHandle<()>>::new();
    for _ in 1..=5 {
        let f = Arc::clone(&foo);
        let t = thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", f);
        });
        threads.push(t);
    }
    threads.into_iter().for_each(|t| t.join().unwrap());

    1
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c964015ab5ef4dfae8faa38871c65ba3)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use for *scoped threads* (provided by [`crossbeam::scope`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) or the higher-level utilities of [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/)), which allow you to simply use an `&Foo` inside the threads. This avoids needing to move the value into and out of an `Arc` at all.

Also, if you use `rayon` you can greatly simplify your code by removing all of the explicit thread creation and joining in favor of its parallel iterators.

```rust
use rayon::iter::{ParallelIterator, IntoParallelIterator};

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(0);
    let _res = process(&foo);
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(u8);

fn process(foo: &Foo) -> u8 {
    (1..=5).into_par_iter().for_each(|_i: usize| {
        println!("{:?}", foo);
    });
    1
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. However, it doesn't quite address a use case that I simplified out of my example. What I'm attempting to do is closer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70716589/12162258) example, where I am discovering work as part of the computation and don't know its extent a priori. Do you have any recommendations in that context (imagine that `from` in the linked example is `foo` here)? Happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: @thisisrandy If you'd like to talk about patterns then there is e.g. the actor model.

Comment: @thisisrandy [`rayon::join`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/fn.join.html) might be a good fit if your new discoveries can be expressed as "here are two subdivisions of the work". If not, then use `crossbeam::scope` as I linked first — it lets you create threads explicitly within the scope.

Comment: @KevinReid I didn't fully appreciate what `crossbeam::scope` offers when I looked at it last night. From the docs, "... this thread is scoped, meaning it's guaranteed to terminate before the scope exits, allowing it to reference variables outside the scope." A perfect fit!